# Show Notification if app is playing

Tags: android, notifications

I wrote an streaming app and want an notification if the stream is playing. 
How I can code it? In general the stream starts via an activity. Is it possible to make the notification showing if the activity plays?

Comment: See the [documentation for the status bar notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). It's all in there. Preferably you set the `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` flag so that your notification behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a notification when it starts and cancel the notification when it stops

Comment: Thanks. Only one problem persists, I use the standard notification but my eclipse show at this line an error: notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

Comment: I created an notification that starts when player starts and stops when player stops. BUT it shows as a normal notification, I can delete it in my notification bar. But this isnt what I want, I want something similar to the notification which PowerAmp and Mortplayer shows. Can someone help me?

Comment: See @alextsc's comment above: you want FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT.